# How do I extract text in between only the first two occurances of a string?

Tags: regex, perl

I am pretty new to computer programming and am trying to write a script that takes all of the text in between the first and second `>` symbol in a large fasta file and outputs it into a different file. The question that I really need answered is if there is a regex command that allows me to only take the text located in between the first and the second `>` symbols in the file.

I have found a lot online about taking text in between two strings, but I haven't find anything anywhere on taking text between only the first and second occurrences of those strings when they appear multiple times in a file.  I am running perl version 5.010.

Comment: Please show your data

Comment: According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format) the `">"` should be the first symbol on the line.. this information is missing in your question.

Comment: Future reference: whenever you're stuck with a regular expression use a tool that highlights and explains parts of what the expressions are doing like regex buddy or http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/perl/index.html

Answer (score 3):

Seems easy enough: `/>([^>]*)>/`

Explanation:

A regex always finds the first (leftmost) match, so the first `>` is easy. "Find all text up to the next `>`" is equivalent to "find all following non-`>` characters", which is where we get `[^>]*` from.

The parens `( )` serve to capture the matched text in `$1`.

Answer (score 3):

By default, regular expressions are greedy, it means that regexp will try to match as many text as possible. To avoid this you can specify symbols which shouldn't be present between > and >, as it was proposed:

```
>([^>]*)>/
```

Or you can just switch regexp engine to lazy mode by adding ? to quantifier:

```
>(.*?)>
```

or

```
>(.+?)>
```

Regexp is simpler, result is same.

So:

```
if ($content =~ m/>(.*?)>/gs) {
    print "Captured: $1"
}
```